# php/username: Page is still showing a deleted data

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to create these pages. First page takes the info of the user can then saves it on phpadmin, then it takes u to a selecting date of entry and exit page. However, where the user enters the entry and exit timing and then a table of attributes, no,entry date, exit date and the username gets saved. But the problem is, the username isn't remaining the same. Like when I created these pages yesterday, everything was working fine, but now, there is a problem, I deleted some customers name and re-entered new ones but when i try to use php, it keeps showing the old username. Here is an example, 
in this image, just after i pick on the registration form to input data, the username and password of an already deleted person starts appearing:

[image]

In this image, after i enter a DIFFERENT username from before, it still takes the username from my old deleted database and puts it in my phpadmin. For example, I put a username xand1 put as seen on the top of the screen, username took the value andy91 which is from my old database:

[image]

Here is my code for registration:

```
<?php
        $firstnameError = $lastnameError = $usernameError = $passwordError = $birthdateError = $mobileError = $emailError = "";
    // Check if data are posted.
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $firstname = $lastname = $username = $password = $birthdate = $mobile = $email = "";
        $errorOccured = false;

        if (isset($_POST['tsmFirstName'])){
            $firstname = trim($_POST['tsmFirstName']);
            if (strlen($firstname) == 0){
                $firstnameError = "First Name is missing";
                $errorOccured = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            $firstnameError = "First Name is missing";
        }

        //Checking last name
        if (isset($_POST['tsmLastName'])){
            $lastname = trim($_POST['tsmLastName']);
            if (strlen($lastname) == 0){
                $lastnameError = "First Name is missing";
                $errorOccured = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            $lastnameError = "First Name is missing";
        }

        //checking the username
        if (isset($_POST['tsmUserName'])){
            $username = trim($_POST['tsmUserName']);
            $usernameLenght = strlen($username);
            if ($usernameLenght == 0){
                $usernameError = "First Name is missing";
                $errorOccured = true;
            }
            elseif ($usernameLenght < 4){
                $usernameError = "Your username should be minimum 4 characters";
                $errorOccured = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            $usernameError = "First Name is missing";
        }


        //checking the password
        if (isset($_POST['tsmPassword'])){
            $password = trim($_POST['tsmPassword']);
            if (strlen($password) == 0){
                $passwordError = "First Name is missing";
                $errorOccured = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            $passwordError = "First Name is missing";
        }

        //checking the birthdate
        if (isset($_POST['tsmBirthDate'])){
            $birthdate = trim($_POST['tsmBirthDate']);
            if (strlen($birthdate) == 0){
                $birthdateError = "First Name is missing";
                $errorOccured = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            $birthdateError = "First Name is missing";
        }

        // checking the mobile
        if (isset($_POST['tsmMobile'])){
            $mobile = trim($_POST['tsmMobile']);
            if (strlen($mobile) == 0){
                $mobileError = "First Name is missing";
                $errorOccured = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            $mobileError = "Mobile is missing";
        }

        //checking the email
        if (isset($_POST['tsmEmail'])){
            $email = trim($_POST['tsmEmail']);
            if (strlen($email) == 0){
                $emailError = "Email is missing";
                $errorOccured = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            $emailError = "Email is missing";
        }                                                       


        if(!$errorOccured){
            require_once("connection.php");

        $_SESSION['tsmUserName']=$username;
        var_dump($_SESSION);
            $keychain= sha1($username);
            $my_query="INSERT INTO users (id, firstname, lastname, username, password, birthdate, mobile, email, status, keychain) VALUES (NULL,'$firstname','$lastname','$username','$password','2016-1-1','$mobile','$email','0','$keychain')";
            $result=mysqli_query($connection,$my_query);
            if($result){
                $message_mail = "Dear $firstname, <br> Thank You for registering with us. Click now on the link below to activate your account. <br> $keychain <br><br> Thank You.";
                $subject_mail= "Your account has been created";
                $to_mail = $email;
                $headers[]= 'MIME-Version 1.0';
                $headers[]= 'content-type:text/html; charset=utf8';
                $headers[]= 'From: admin@tassimo.com';
                mail($to_mail,$subject_mail,$message_mail,implode("\r\n",$headers));
                //after email is sent redirect to thank you page.
                header("Location:completed.php?task=done");
                exit();
                echo 'Thank You';
            }
                else{
                    echo "<b> Error unable to post. </b>";
                    mysqli_error($connection);
                }
                mysqli_close($connection);
            }

        }


?>
```

and here is for timing

```
<?php
session_start();
$EntryError=$ExitError="";
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $entrydate = $exitdate = "";
        $errorOccured = false;

        if (isset($_POST['tsmdate'])){
            $entrydate = trim($_POST['tsmdate']);
            if (strlen($entrydate) == 0){
                $EntryError = "date is missing";
                $errorOccured = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            $EntryError = "date is missing";
        }

        // checking for last name
        if (isset($_POST['tsmexit'])){
            $exitdate = trim($_POST['tsmexit']);
            if (strlen($exitdate) == 0){
                $ExitError = "First Name is missing";
                $errorOccured = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            $ExitError = "last Name is missing";
        }
        $ids=$_SESSION['tsmUserName'];
        var_dump($_SESSION);
        if(!$errorOccured){
            require_once("connection.php");
            $my_query="INSERT INTO timing (`No`, `Entry Date and Time`, `Exit Date and Time`, `Username`) VALUES (NULL,'$EntryError','$exitdate','$ids')";
            $result=mysqli_query($connection,$my_query);
            if($result)
            {
                echo 'thank you';
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'error';
            }
            mysqli_close($connection);
        }
    }   
?>
```

Comment: and you have code for all this?

Comment: ok well if you're just going to post pretty pictures, then we can't help you. Good luck with this and oh... start accepting answers were some gave you solutions.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry i forgot putting in my codes hang on.. And what do u mean by accepting answers?

Comment: @Fred-ii- i put my codes in

Comment: var_dump($_POST) in complete.php

Comment: is new db in .. require_once("connection.php");

Comment: @HamzaKhan Read about **[accepting answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)**.

Comment: @flakerimi. Aside from the registration page, every page says the value of tsmUserName is andy91 :/ idk why..

Comment: @Qirel I don't see any answer here.

Comment: @flakerimi yea the db of all the tables is in connection.php

Comment: @flakerimi Check out OPs history of questions - 8 asked, 0 accepted.

Comment: @HamzaKhan People will not help you if you don't accept answers. Qirel is right.

Comment: @flakerimi sorry i am new here i dont really know much. Sure, i will accept answers now that i know what it is thanks

Comment: Doesn't mean one should blindly accept answers, but a 8/0 relation looks bad :p

Comment: Side-note: you need to set `$errorOccured` to `true` for the cases when the POST values are not set.

Comment: @Mikey will check that thanks.. However, plz help me out with this username issue as well its driving me insaneee

Comment: Are you sure your browser is just not auto completing the fields?

Comment: @Mikey really dont know.. How do i fix that

Comment: @Mikey i just restarted my pc and now its saying tsmusername is unidentified :/

Answer (score 0):

All of yours first errors have same description "First name is missing". I think you should change that. It will be good if 2nd code which you upload have isset of $_SESSION['tsmUserName'].

About first screen you can delete browser data to remove auto-fill option.

Comment: yea will change the first name thing.. the thing is, for second page, i dont want the user to enter his username again, and i dont really get how to use isset unless u wanna get the value of input or something :/ my codes were working fine before i tried to make username the primary key.. I did remove it from being primary but the error retains